# How can I persist an ansible variable across ansible roles?

Tags: ansible

I've registered a variable in a play.

```
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  sudo: no
  vars_files:
    - vars.yml
  tasks:
    - name: build load balancer
      os_load_balancer: net=mc_net ext_net=vlan3320 name=load_balancer protocol=HTTPS port=80
      register: my_lb
```

I can access that variable fine, until I make the request inside a role.

For example, in a separate role in the same run, I want to access that registered variable:

```
- debug: var=my_lb
```

I get the following output:

```
{'msg': "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: One or more undefined variables: 'my_lb' is undefined", 'failed': True}
```

How can I access variables registered in a separate role, within the same play?

> Edit for clarity of how things piece together:
>
> ```
> Top Play
> -includes: 
>   - Sub play 1
>     - registers variable foo
>   - Sub play 2
>     -includes:
>       - sub play A
>         - role 1 
>         - role 2
>         - role 3 
>           - references variable foo in template
>       - Sub play B
>   - Sub play 3
> ```

Comment: who are you? if you know what I mean.. ;-).. can you add your call to the role in your playbook?

Comment: lol. This play is building resources and, I have another play which is configuring the hosts.  They are all involked from a top level play.

Comment: Didn't really understand how many playbooks you have and which play calls which play and includes which role. In OP you mention role, in comment you don't mention role, only plays.

Comment: Did you try the suggested answer of `set_fact` in a `pre_task`? I'm interested if that solved your problem as it should.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**NB: This was written referring to Ansible 1.X. I suspect variable parsing and scoping has changed considerably with Ansible 2.0, so bear that in mind. I'll try to update the answer if I get time (or maybe someone else will answer for v2.0!)**

There are two options here. The simplest is to define the variables in your top-level playbook, then propagate them down into your various roles. You can either set these as simple vars, or use `pre_tasks` to lookup / calculate values dynamically, e.g.

```
vars:
    foo_static: "value_bar"

pre_tasks:
    - set_fact:
        foo_ncpu: "{{ ansible_processor_vcpus }}"

  roles:
    - {role: role1, role1_var1: "{{foo_static}}", role1_var2: "{{foo_ncpu}}" }
    - {role: role2, role2_var1: "{{foo_static}}", role2_var2: "{{foo_ncpu}}" }
```

The second option requires that you add a task to whichever role you need to extract a variable from (though since all ansible roles are open-source, that should be easy enough). The trick is to use [set_fact](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/set_fact_module.html) to export a variable as a 'host_fact', e.g.

```
- name: Export role1_varfoo to a 'host-fact' type variable
  set_fact:
    role1_varfoo: "{{ role1_varfoo }}"
```

Which can then be accessed later like so:

```
  vars:
    role2_varfoo: "{{ hostvars['myhost']['role1_varfoo']}}"
```

As described in [this bit of the ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables).

Note that if you always want to lookup the hostvars of the current machine you're running commands on (without knowing what it's actually called in the ansible hosts file), you can use the variable `inventory_hostname` like so:

```
  vars:
    role2_varfoo: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['role1_varfoo']}}"
```

(Note lack of quote-marks, since it's a variable, not a string-literal.)

Slightly awkward, but those combinations have met all my needs so far.

Comment: Based on my trials the second option does not work unless I'm doing something wrong when referring the host as hostvars['localhost']. According to this on the same link you quote: Facts: "There are other places where variables can come from, but these are a type of variable that are discovered, not set by the user." I tried it and got this error: fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'ec2_instance_id'"}. So am I doing something wrong then?

Comment: Hi @einarc - it's hard to tell without context whether you're simply trying to run that command on a machine that's not an AWS EC2 instance? But also, it's quite possible things have changed since Ansible hit 2.0, I think the variable parsing / scoping has altered somewhat so my answer likely needs updating.

Comment: In my case variant with inventory_hostname isn't worked, also I don't have names for my machines in invetory file, so correct variant is `hostvars[groups['group_name'][0]].varName`

Comment: @TimStaley It was simply that the play on the playbook didn't have the gather_facts set to true so it wasn't populating the variables in the host, so while it couldn't find localhost, there was no variable to look at.

Answer (score 4):

Try moving your variable declarations into a `pre_task` block. Variables set here should be available within and following roles.

https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_roles.html#roles

e.g.

```
pre_tasks:
    - name: build load balancer
      os_load_balancer: net=mc_net ext_net=vlan3320 name=load_balancer protocol=HTTPS port=80
      register: my_lb

roles:
  - { role: some_role }
```

Answer (score 4):

> Update: To access the variable using the hostvars syntax use the appropriate host GROUP variable rather than the host that executed the set_fact:

```
hostvars[inventory_hostname]['variable']
```

---

To broaden the accepted question.

1.-You can define ANOTHER role where you register the variable and then set it there then refer that variable from multiple roles. AS LONG as the roles are in the same play.
Docu here:
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-examples

> Generally speaking, variables set in one role are available to others. This means if you have a roles/common/vars/main.yml you can set variables in there and make use of them in other roles and elsewhere in your playbook

Edit: Clarification, this applies for REGISTERED and set variables in Ansible 2.x in my experience.

2.-As far as using hostvars goes, I tried it myself and failed with this error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'ec2_instance_id'"}
```

I my case I was doing the following.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  roles:
  - { role: role_1 }
post_tasks:
- name: Check instance variables within localhost
  debug: var={{ hostvars['localhost']['ec2_instance_id'] }}
```

On role 1 I had:

```
- name: register instance_id
  set_fact: ec2_instance_id="{{ item.id }}"
  with_items: "{{ ec2_instance.instances }}"
```

Although according to this old thread, the hostvar approach should work:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/1934

Answer (score 1):

How abt passing it as parameter to role. I'm assuming such (register) variables aren't passed implicitly (like hotvars are).

```
- { role: my_role, my_lb: "{{my_lb}}" }
```

Comment: I'm getting somewhere, how best to raise the variable scope into the top play though?

Comment: @J0hnG4lt you can set it as a 'host fact', I've used this myself and explained in my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/33780065/725650)